# JaCoCo instruments test files instead of actual sources

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, code-coverage, jacoco

first of all out setup: We're deploying an application as war-file with several Servlets on a tomcat, which is then started with the jacoco agent active. The tests we run are integration tests and the jacoco-it.exec file is created on tomcat shutdown and even contains data. However, even though our tests touch all the Servlets, only a single class is shown as "covered" and that's the private constructor of an enum (which is called in a static way by the enum).

*Update inbetween: I now noticed, that the "sessions" part shows all the classes covered and it includes the mentioned enum along with the test classes, which is odd, as they shouldn't have been included (they weren't put on tomcat). The enum was also used in tests, which would explain it being covered*

I've done the same procedure with jacoco-integration-test-coverage in a previous project and it all worked out fine, so I have no clue, what's the matter.

I tried adding the includeBootstrapClasses property and some other tweaks (setting dumpOnExit to true/false etc.) but none of them worked. I even tried offline instrumentation, which only resulted in the same result. Adding `static {}` blocks to the code of the servlets, which just print "foo" to the console are not marked as covered as well, even though the tomcat-log contains the messages.

Jacoco config in pom:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which 
                        is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed. -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                            <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo 
                                runtime agent. -->
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created 
                        after unit tests have been run. -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- The Executions required by unit tests are omitted. -->
                    <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which 
                        is passed as VM argument when Maven the Failsafe plugin is executed. -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                            <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo 
                                runtime agent. -->
                            <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests after 
                        integration tests have been run. -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                            <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

failsafeArgLine (used in config) is as follows:
`-javaagent:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.2.201409121644/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.2.201409121644-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/jenkins/jenkins/jobs/dms-coverage/workspace/com.example.dms/target/jacoco-it.exec`

surefireArgLine is not important as there's no unit tests but only integration tests for now.

Note, that jacoco DOES instrument things but not the classes on tomcat but the test classes.

If you have any idea, what's wrong here, please give me a hint.

Thanks and regards,
Kay

Comment: Can you please include the exact JaCoCo configuration and command line?

Also, how do you know your servlets are being executed by the tests?

Comment: added them - the failsafeArgLine is exactly the jacoco-agent-line, that is used on tomcat.